# Создание буфера из массива объектов

Tags: javascript, node.js, сериализация, v8

Как преобразовать массив, который состоит из объектов в буффер?
PS: `JSON.stringify()` не предлагать, ибо объекты огромные(~1гиг)

Comment: Для начала попробуйте рассказать как вы себе представляете преобразование объекта в буфер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать [v8 Serialization API](https://nodejs.org/api/v8.html#v8_serialization_api):

```js
const v8 = require('v8');

const array1 = [{ foo: 42 }];

const buffer = v8.serialize(array1);
console.log(buffer);

const array2 = v8.deserialize(buffer);
console.log(array2);
```

```
<Buffer ff 0d 41 01 6f 22 03 66 6f 6f 49 54 7b 01 24 00 01>
[ { foo: 42 } ]
```